# Bind returns failure on UDP Port

Tags: c, udp

Consider the following code:

```
iSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
memset(&sSocketAddr, 0, sizeof(sSocketAddr));

sSocketAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sSocketAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
sSocketAddr.sin_port = htons(10003);
Res = bind(iSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&sSocketAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

In the above code bind returns -1. But for any other port number it returns 0(no error). I need to use 10003 as per UDP client requirement. How can this be made to work?

Comment: Have you checked the actual error?

Comment: What *is* the actual error? You can't expect people to answer questions like this when you omit the most important information of all.

Comment: Probably some other application is listening on that port. You can find this by running `netstat -a | grep "49184"`

Comment: @Corbin and @ EJP: How do I check the actual error? If I would have known all that, i would have found the answer myself :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the bind man page (http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) :

> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

I think it is the standard procedure in every POSIX call, there is an integer named errno that contains the value of the actual error. You can either check its value manually, or use primitives as perror or strerror (http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/perrorman.html)

```
if (Res  == -1) { // some error has occurred
    // prints "socket error: " + the error message:
    perror("socket error");
}
```

you might wanna `#include<errno.h>` (and `stdio.h` for the printing functions)